# Choose the Startup Form in a Java Application in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, startup

I've created a java application on `netbeans`, and I've built it to get it as `.jar`.

now when I run my `.jar` application it doesn't show anything, I want to run a form in my projet as the default one on the application startup.

In visual studio I used to do as the following :

> ```
> In Solution Explorer, right-click the project and choose Properties.
>
> The Project property page opens with the Application properties displayed.
>
> Choose the form you want as the startup form from the Startup Object drop-down list.
> ```

But I don't know how to do it in `neatbeans` with a java application.

How can I do it ?

Comment: Have you tried to open the `JFrame` in your `main()` method?

Answer (score 7):

In netBeans you can easily select your main class for your project.
In order to do this, right click on the project name, then select properties. Now click on "Run" and where it says "Main class" browse for your desired class.
If I understood your question, this is the solution.